# Text Classification on a custom dataset with spacy v3

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am really struggling to make things work with the new spacy v3 version. The documentation is full. However, I am trying to run a training loop in a script.

(I am also not able to perform text classification training with CLI approach).

Data are publically available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/koaning/tokenwiser/main/data/oos-intent.jsonl).

```py
import pandas as pd
from spacy.training import Example
import random

TRAIN_DATA = pd.read_json('data.jsonl', lines = True)

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

config = {
    "threshold": 0.5,
}

textcat = nlp.add_pipe("textcat", config=config, last=True)

label = TRAIN_DATA['label'].unique()

for label in label:
    textcat.add_label(str(label))

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
nlp.begin_training()


# Loop for 10 iterations
for itn in range(100):
    # Shuffle the training data
    losses = {}
    
    TRAIN_DATA = TRAIN_DATA.sample(frac = 1)

    # Batch the examples and iterate over them
    for batch in spacy.util.minibatch(TRAIN_DATA.values, size=4):
        texts = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text, entities in batch]
        annotations = [{"cats": entities} for text, entities in batch]

        # uses an example object rather than text/annotation tuple
        print(texts)
        print(annotations)
        examples = [Example.from_dict(a)]
        
        nlp.update(examples, losses=losses)
    if itn % 20 == 0:
        print(losses)
```

Comment: It's strongly recommended you use the CLI training instead of writing your own training loop, because writing your own training loop there's lots of things that can go wrong. If you're having trouble with the CLI approach (or in general) feel free to ask for help on the forums, which can handle issues that aren't appropriate for Stack Overflow questions. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions

Comment: There are also multiple examples of classification ("textcat") here. https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials